# ata error on not hdd device

Tags: linux, ata, dmesg

So my dmesg is spammed with this over and over again:

```
[ 1478.880795] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[ 1478.880803] ata5: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[ 1478.880808] ata5: SError: { DevExch }
[ 1478.880816] ata5: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[ 1478.880820] ata5: hard resetting link
[ 1479.753964] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
[ 1479.764060] ata5: EH complete
```

However when i list my storage devices none of it is actually connected to ata5

```
$ ls -la /sys/block/                                                                                                                                                                                                                         [1]
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 13. Apr 15:43 .
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0 13. Apr 15:43 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 13. Apr 15:43 sda -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 13. Apr 15:44 sr0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sr0
```

How do i find out what the faulty device is?

Comment: ok found out it was the eSata port, i had a usb mouse connected to it.

But only by trial and error what would be a software way to get the device name or smthg?

Answer (score 0):

From comments,

> ok found out it was the eSata port, i had a usb mouse connected to it.

It's a combo eSATA+USB port.

USB devices connected to that special ports are listed with `lsusb` like any other USB device.

Answer (score 0):

If you look further up in `dmesg`, during the boot process, when the controller is initialized, there are messages about the various ports, together with information what the chipset finds behind those ports, which you can use e.g. to identify the harddisk attached. You can also see supported speeds etc.

So you can attach harddisks or other devices with known id to each port in turn, and in this way find out which physical port belongs to which port number.

The assignment of port numbers to physical ports in general is motherboard or card dependent, and it would be the duty of the manufacturer to provide information about this assignment, but unfortunately no manufacturer seems to be willing to do that.